# Spring mvc send entity from server to client

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I m developping a webservice using SpringFramework (STS). I'm working on 2 projects: the webservice/backend and the client (frontend). My problem is that when I try to send one of my entity object from the server to the client, using a url with parameter, I get an Error 400 on the web page but no error on the console. I get to pass a list of objects without error but when its the Entity I need it doesn't work. Knowing that when I call the URL on backend directly I get the data I need. The only problem is to send them to frontend.

Here's the code server side:

My entity: UserProfile.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profile")
public class UserProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "coverPhoto", nullable = false)
    private String coverPhoto;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_modelLibrary")
    private ModelLibrary modelLibrary;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_shop")
    private Shop shop;

    public UserProfile(){}

    public UserProfile(User user){
        this.user = new User();
        this.setCoverPhoto("");
        this.setUser(user);
        this.setModelLibrary(new ModelLibrary(user));
        this.setShop(new Shop(user));
    }
    // Getters & setters
}
```

The controller (Server side):UserProfileController.java

```
@RestController
public class UserProfileController {
    private UserProfileService userProfileService;

    // Recuperer les infos de session
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getProfile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserProfile getMyProfile(@PathVariable("id") String userId) {
        Application.context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        userProfileService = (UserProfileService) Application.context.getBean("userProfileService");
        UserProfile userProfile = userProfileService.getUserProfileByUserId(userId);
        System.out.println(userProfile.getUser().toString());
        return userProfile;
    }
}
```

And now the code client side:
UserProfileController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserProfileController {

    private UserProfileService uProfileService = new UserProfileServiceImpl();
    private UserProfile uprofile;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/myProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getMyProfile(HttpSession session, Model model){
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("Sessionuser");
            UserProfile uProfile = this.uProfileService.getUserProfileByUserId(user.getId());
            this.uprofile = uProfile;
            System.out.println("Get profile "+ uProfile.getUser().getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("userProfile", this.uprofile);
            return "myprofile";
        }
}
```

(The UserProfileService only return the result of DAO methods so no need to type it.)

The UserProfileDAO.java (Client side)

```
@Repository("userProfileDAO")
public class UserProfileDAOImpl implements UserProfileDAO{


    @Override
    public UserProfile getUserProfileByUserId(String user_id) {
        return new RestTemplate().getForObject(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "getProfile/" + user_id, UserProfile.class);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**spring ModelAndView.addObject() method**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

Try the following code:

```
model.addObject("userProfile", this.uprofile);
```

Instead of:

```
model.addAttribute("userProfile", this.uprofile);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried and it still doesn't work. After debug I kinda figured out that the probleme comes from 

return new RestTemplate().getForObject(WebService.getWebServiceUrl() + "getProfile/" + user_id, UserProfile.class);

'coz I get the error pops just after this and the prints coded after don't print...

Comment: Ok , I haven't see it but the addObject() is the best way of doing it, and  it works fine for me.